# Scala async vs. Java ForkJoinTask

Tags: java, scala, asynchronous, async-await, forkjoinpool

Some time ago I discovered the [Scala Async Project](https://github.com/scala/async). The question is: what is so magical in this `async` blocks which can not be implemented via plain functions (without macro expansion)?

Let's look at the first example from the introduction:

```
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.async.Async.{async, await}

val future = async {
    val f1 = async { ...; true }
    val f2 = async { ...; 42 }
    if (await(f1)) await(f2) else 0
}
```

I do not see anything in the above example which can not be written in pure Java. This code does exactly the same thing:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

// First define a helper method for creating async blocks:
public static <T> ForkJoinTask<T> async(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    return new RecursiveTask<T>() {
        @Override
        protected T compute() {
            return supplier.get();
        }
    }.fork();
}

ForkJoinTask<Integer> future = ForkJoinPool.commonPool().submit(() -> {
    ForkJoinTask<Boolean> f1 = async(() -> true);
    ForkJoinTask<Integer> f2 = async(() -> 42);

    if (f1.join()) {
        return f2.join();
    } else {
        return 42;
    }
});
```

What can Scala `async` do that Java can't? Maybe in case of some more complex scenarios? What do I miss?

Comment: I think it's the case that "anything" in Scala can be rewritten as Pure Java .. given enough time and effort :|

Comment: FYI [It doesn't answers java part directly, but anyways](https://github.com/scala/async#comparison-with-direct-use-of-future-api)

Comment: @user2864740 and anything written in Java can be reimplemented in pure assembler :-)

Comment: Which code seems more concise to you?

Comment: No, there must be a killer feature of `async` except the syntax. One idea which comes to my mind is that `async` works on any thread pool, not necessary a `ForkJoinPool`.

Comment: any thread can go in a thread pool

Comment: also, your syntax here is java8, with lambda which are already significantly less verbose than plain old java7 was. And java8 is but a fortnight old

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one crucial difference in how the two snippets you posted work under the hood: **blocking operations**.

The `scala-async` snippet is roughly equivalent to:

```
val future = {
  val f1 = Future { ...; true }
  val f2 = Future { ...; 42 }
  f1.flatMap { b =>
    if(b) f2 else Future.successful(0)
  }
}
```

This is a callback-based code. There are no operations in there that would block any thread. Only future wrapping and callback registering (which happens under the hood of `flatMap` in this case). In other words, everything is *asynchronous* there.

On the other hand, the `join` method from Java's fork-join pool *does* block the thread.

No blocking operations is a significant performance/scalability advantage, because - greatly simplifying - no blocking => less threads needed => less OS resources needed + less context switching.

Summarizing: the purpose of `scala-async` is to make non-blocking, callback based, *asynchronous* processing as natural in its syntax as the standard, blocking approach (like the one you used in Java).

Comment: @njzk2 No, it doesn't and that is the whole point of all the macro magic that `scala-async` does.

Comment: how could await not actually wait for the answer? i.e. how can it continue execution depending on a value that the thread computing said value has not computed yet?

Comment: @njzk2 `await` wait only "syntactically" - it is made to look like a blocking call, while being non-blocking under the hood. What _really_ happens there is a "continuation" callback being registered. That transformation happens in compile-time (`await` and `async` are _macros_, not actual method calls).

Comment: @njzk2 Look into [the sources](https://github.com/scala/async/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/async/Async.scala) - it's explicitly stated that `await` calls are translated to `onComplete` calls by the `await` macro.

Comment: Then that would mean that the rest of the method is either executed on a new thread or on the thread used by the async on which we await?

Comment: @njzk2 Yep, exactly. Where that continuation code executes is actually controlled by implicit `executor` argument of the `onComplete` method. See [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future).

Comment: that seems quite dangerous. (as does any type of macro, anyway). But that's probably just me.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I made some tests and achieved the situation where the Java code works slower, because it does not utilize all the threads (due to blocking on `join`): https://gist.github.com/orionll/9771204